# React Router - History

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a react app with multiple routes. On one of my routes I only want to render a certain component if the user navigated from a specific route. How do I check the previous path used to get to the current route? Thanks

Comment: How are users able to navigate from the "from" route to the "target" route? Can you share a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you've tried so far? Provide details regarding any issues, errors, etc.

Comment: So the structure of the project is like this..
- Project Categories
   - Table of items for each category
      -  Each item has a separate page

The project categories link to a page which displays the items for each category, each item is then linked to a unique page.

When a user visited the the page with all the items from each category, I want to know if the user was in a unique item page before navigating to the items page..

Comment: Please show us in code. A simple approach could be to maintain your own history stack and just check the previous location's pathname on the route that cares about it. Another option is to pass some value in route state that is checked on each routed component.

Comment: I got it sorted with session storage, thanks